# I'm installing react project tended to work on iOS but I got a problem of Cocoapods

Tags: react-native, npm-install, npx

Hi I'm new to react and I just follow the instructions of official website and install the react project.

```
npx react-native init Awesomeproject
```

After I run the code above, the result is like:

```
✔ Downloading template
✔ Copying template
✔ Processing template
✖ Installing CocoaPods dependencies (this may take a few minutes)
✖ Installing CocoaPods dependencies (this may take a few minutes)
error Error: Failed to install CocoaPods dependencies for iOS project, which is required by this template.
Please try again manually: "cd ./AwesomeProject/ios && pod install".
CocoaPods documentation: https://cocoapods.org/
```

I tried many ways to fix this. Like I enter iOS file and type `pod install`, and still doesn't work:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/universal-darwin20/rbconfig.rb:229: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/sbin in PATH, mode 040777
Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `../node_modules/react-     native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `RCT-Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-   party-podspecs/RCT-Folly.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `glog` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-  party-podspecs/glog.podspec`
Downloading dependencies
Installing CocoaAsyncSocket (7.6.5)
Installing DoubleConversion (1.1.6)
Installing FBLazyVector (0.64.2)
Installing FBReactNativeSpec (0.64.2)
Installing Flipper (0.75.1)
Installing Flipper-DoubleConversion (1.1.7)
Installing Flipper-Folly (2.5.3)
Installing Flipper-Glog (0.3.6)
Installing Flipper-PeerTalk (0.0.4)

[!] Error installing Flipper-PeerTalk
[!] /usr/local/bin/git clone.   https://github.com/priteshrnandgaonkar/peertalk.git   /var/folders/y9/8_9j99jd3zx74b7xyfyl94740000gn/T/d20210630-17237-1uay6lt --  template= --single-branch --depth 1 --branch v0.0.3

正克隆到 '/var/folders/y9/8_9j99jd3zx74b7xyfyl94740000gn/T/d20210630-17237-   1uay6lt'...
fatal: 无法访问 'https://github.com/priteshrnandgaonkar/peertalk.git/'：    LibreSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 60
```

I'don't know. I'm not in USA now and it might be the network issue. I'm stuck in this for a long time and really want to figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: how to set up? Is that npm install -g react-native-cli?

Comment: no, you have to choose the xcode command line tool in xcode :https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup#command-line-tools

Comment: Never mind, I fixed it up. It's the network connection issue